# AttributeError at /admin/blog/post 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, django

I have a simple blog code in Django , I write the error and my codes:

there is my codes
models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post


class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name= 'home')
]
```

and home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in object_list %}
    <div class="post-entry">
      <h2><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

There is Error message after running code:

```
AttributeError at /admin/blog/post
'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/post
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
Exception Location: C:\Users\nilaroz\.virtualenvs\blog-Keg_c4F1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\http.py, line 295, in is_same_domain
Python Executable:  C:\Users\nilaroz\.virtualenvs\blog-Keg_c4F1\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['D:\\MyDjangoProject\\blog',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python38-32\\DLLs',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python38-32\\lib',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\nilaroz\\.virtualenvs\\blog-Keg_c4F1',
 'C:\\Users\\nilaroz\\.virtualenvs\\blog-Keg_c4F1\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 31 Jan 2021 19:53:08 +0000
```

why? I don't make any list!
what's mean "'list' object has no attribute 'lower'"?
I think maybe Django makes a list when call for loop!

```
{% for post in object_list %}
```

how I do solve this problem?

Comment: Are you really accessing the view that you describes via /admin/blog/post ? That seems to be related to django admin panel. Also, at no point you use the lower function in the code you show so it's weird...

Comment: the admin panel works before add the views, and after i add some data and add views (home.html and base.html) it's stopped! and show me this  error! I don't use of list or any lower() method and function...! the error message don't show anything..! it is a bad message

Answer (score 1):

I find the solve:
I by mistake write

```
'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
```

in the

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

while should write it in the  settings.py in "TEMPLATES"

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
    },
]
```

I recommend  that do not code when are very tired. Sleep!